# How should package modules import from each other?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have this package structure:

```
widget/
    __init__.py
    core.py
    extension.py
```

__init__.py is empty.

core.py contains this:

```
import widget.extension as extension
```

It works, but it feels like I'm side-stepping the package and just importing it from the global path (i.e. climbing out of it only to look back into it). If I just `import extension` in core.py it doesn't work. Does this matter? Am I wrong in the first place? Should I instead be pulling both of these modules into `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming you are using Python 3; in Python 2, `import extension` would work as Python 2 will first look for a local, relative import before looking for a global, absolute reference.

You have two more options:

```
from widget import extension
```

and

```
from . import extension
```

The latter imports relative to the *current* package, which allows you to rename your `widget` package without having to update all your internal imports. What you use is a matter of style and taste.

Comment: I very much like the last one. Sadly, I am trapped in Python 2.6 for the foreseeable future. It's embedded in the app I code for at work. I take it `from . import extension` doesn't work in 2.x.

Comment: Sounds like you should have elaborated on how `import extension` didn't work for you then. :-) `from . import extension` works *just fine* on Python 2.x, as of Python 2.3.

Comment: Wow, I was doubly-confused. It wasn't `extension.py` where I was having the problem. It was `test/test_extension.py`, which couldn't `import extension` from outside the test folder. I think I was coding way too late.

Comment: Sounds like a resource problem instead to me: not enough caffeine. :-P Problem solved?

Comment: I think it is for the moment. Thanks.